# Problems with mocking jsonp requests using mockjax in qunit

Tags: ajax, mocking, jsonp, qunit, mockjax

I'd like to use mockjax with qunit but can't get it to work.
Here is a simple test I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/shapeshifta/3YNB2/

```
asyncTest('Response returns jsonp', function() {
    $.mockjax({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json*',
        contentType: 'text/json',
        proxy: 'mocks/twitter.json'
    });
    window.abcdef123456 = function() {
        start();
        ok(true, 'JSONP Callback executed');
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Javascript&callback=?',
        jsonpCallback: 'abcdef123456',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        error: function() {},
        complete: function() {}
    });
    $.mockjaxClear();
});
```

Works like a charm without the mockjax code but does not really work with it... Am I doing soemthing wrong? Tried to use sinon.js but it has some issues with asynchronous test so I wanted to switch to mockjax. But my code just keeps asking twitter for data although mockjax should mock my request...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working:

```
asyncTest('Response returns jsonp', function() {

    $.mockjax({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json*',
        contentType: 'text/json',
        proxy: 'mocks/twitter.json'
    });

    function onSucceed(data) {
        start();
        ok(true, 'JSONP completed');
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Javascript&callback=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: onSucceed,
        error: function() { alert('error'); },
        complete: function() { $.mockjaxClear(); }
    });
});​
```

Comment: What would be in `mocks/twitter.json` ?  How is using proxy any different than using responseText ?

Comment: In the `mocks/twitter.json` file, you would have just a JSON object in text notations .. for example `{ "message" : "I am mock data" }`